# renderflex overflowed error in modalbottomsheet in flutter when using keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a textfield in my modal bottom sheet. When I open the keyboard to type, it shows me error for renderflex overflowed. I used singlechildscrollview and isScrollControlled true, still error comes up. Any solutions?

```
return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Builder(
          builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: 350,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
              color: cardColor2,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ValueListenableBuilder(
                          valueListenable: _image,
                          builder: (BuildContext context, File f, Widget? child) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: f.path!='' ? 180 : 280,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: 'Type your question here',
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        ValueListenableBuilder(
                          valueListenable: _image,
                          builder: (BuildContext context, File f, Widget? child) {
                            return f.path!='' ? SizedBox(
                              width: 150.0,
                              height: 100.0,
                              child: Image.file(
                                _image.value,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ) : Container();
                          },
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 1,
                            color: tertiaryTextColor2,
                            width: double.infinity,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _onAlertPress(context);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Add an image',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: backgroundColor2,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {

                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Post',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: backgroundColor2,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: brandYellow,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      isScrollControlled: true,
    );
```

Comment: try to refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554986/13997210) hope its help to you.

Answer (score 0):

**try to remove height of Container** because the height is not enough for other child container or sizedbox

```
return showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Builder(
      builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(

          height: 350, ---------------> remove this

          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
```

Comment: Nah, still not working.

Comment: are you using scaffold? if yes then try this `resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false` inside scaffold

Comment: Nah, I am not using scaffold, I thought of that too.